# Are docker container security limits limited by the host's security limits?

Tags: rhel, docker

Lets say that I have a host which has *max locked memory* set to 64kb:

> [root@host]# ulimit -l
>   64

and a docker container running in that host with no limits:

> [root@container]# ulimit -l
>   unlimited

which security limits setting would be applied to an application running inside the docker container?

Comment: reading [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318543/how-to-set-ulimit-file-descriptor-on-docker-container-the-image-tag-is-phusion#24331638) it seems that by default the host setting have the precendence

Answer (score 1):

As much as it revolts me to say the word, the host ulimit trumps. The container is running in that user space, and acts as any other process would.  It is bound by the same limits.